# When do invariant measures arise from smooth differntial forms?

Tags: measure-theory, differential-geometry, lie-groups, homogeneous-spaces

It is well known that the Haar measure of a Lie group $ G $ arises from a invariant <strike>differential form</strike> density $ |\omega| $ (of top dimension). Also, we know that if we have a closed subgroup $ H \leq G $, then there is the following criterion:

$ \exists $ a $ G $-invariant (Radon) measure $ \mu $ on $ G/H $ iff $ \Delta_G|_H = \Delta_H $ (modular functions on the groups)

Is there a criterion (in general), when a (arbitrary) measure $ \nu $ on a Lie group $ G $ arises from a smooth differential form or a density? I'm particularly interested in the above case: Does the $ G $-invariant measure $ \mu $ arise from a differential form or a density of the manifold $ G/H $?

I guess there is a positive answer to that question, but I don't see how to show that technically (my differential geometry skills are rather moderate). I think what we somehow should use, is the description of the modular functions $ \Delta_G (g) = \det(Ad(g)) $ in the case of Lie groups.

Comment: notice that $G/H$ doesn't have to be orientable, and in that case the measure is not a $n$-form ($n=dim\,G/H$), but a little modification of that, called a smooth density. To see that it's smooth one can convolve it (via the action of $G$) with any compactly supported smooth density on $G$ of integral $1$; as your measure is $G$-invariant, it is equal to the result of the convolution, which is certainly smooth.

Comment: Ok, thanks, that actually was all I needed. Still wondering though, I think there should be a Lie group/differential geometry argument to descend from $ G $ to $ G/H $ (as in the topological group-case, where we construct the measure on $ G/H $ via the measure on $ G $ and Riesz representation theorem)... So if $ | \omega | $ is a $ G $-invariant density on $ G $, I tried to describe the corresponding $ G $-invariant density on $ G/H $, but I did not suceed..

Comment: It's quite simple to construct an invariant $n$-form on $G/H$ ($n=$dim$G/H$): the tangent space at $[1]\in G/H$ is $\mathfrak g/\mathfrak h$; all that you need is a non-$0$ $H$-invariant element in $\bigwedge^n T_{[1]}^*G/H=\bigwedge^n(\mathfrak g/\mathfrak h)^*$, which you then translate to all points of $G/H$. So we need to suppose that the 1-dimensional representation of $H$, $\bigwedge^n(\mathfrak g/\mathfrak h)$, is trivial (relative unimodularity), and it's done.